# how to use state management in build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two widget inside `column`.`topLayer` widget change the `url`. I need to pass to changed url to `bottomLayer`. How to pass it?

```
class MapBoxExample extends StatefulWidget {
  MapBoxExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MapBoxExampleState createState() => _MapBoxExampleState();
}

class _MapBoxExampleState extends State<MapBoxExample> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String url = “”;
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        topLayer(url),
        bottomLayer(url)
          ]))));}}

Widget topLayer(url){
url = “google.com”
...
}

Widget bottomLayer(url){
…
onPressed:()=> print(url);//Value is null
}
```

I tried `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setModelState(() {..}` inside `topLayer`. But this one running always.

Is it possible to use `simple setState` or `bloc` to here?

Comment: You should show more code on `topLayer()` and `bottomLayer()`. It looks inconsistent that `topLayer()` has no parameter but the one in `Column` has a parameter.

Comment: I edited...My actual code is really big. That's why I added this code. same scenario

Answer (score 0):

Make url a variable of MapBoxExample widget. And pass a function that changes the url and setState so the component can be rebuild. Something like this:

```
class MapBoxExample extends StatefulWidget {
  MapBoxExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MapBoxExampleState createState() => _MapBoxExampleState();
}

class _MapBoxExampleState extends State<MapBoxExample> {
String url = “”;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        topLayer(updateUrl),
        bottomLayer(url)
          ]))));}}

updateUrl(String updatedUrl) {
   setState(() => {
      url = updatedUrl;
   })
}

Widget topLayer(url){
//run the method updateUrl passing the updateUrl as parameter
}

Widget bottomLayer(url){
…
onPressed:()=> print(url);//Value is null
}
```